# WebElement.click() causes page refresh

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I have a `<button>` element. I call the `click()` function on this element using chrome webdriver.

```
appDone = driver.FindElement(By.Id(Constants.APP_DONE));
appDone.Click();
```

A strange thing happens in chrome, the page actually get reloaded. A pop up comes 
"Are you sure you want to leave the page? You have unsaved data" Leave/Stay (buttons)

But same click event works fine in other browsers (Edge, IE, Edge). I opened the console in Chrome before clicking the button and placed debugger. Then executed the button click, the console window goes out a new console window comes up.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Things I have tried so far:

- executed the button click using `IJavaScriptExecutor`
- There is an `beforeunload` event in page, so when I pass `onbeforeunload = null`, I don't see the page refresh pop up anymore, but page still refreshes.
- Tried to add `type = button` in the button, still no luck.

This screen works fine when run manually without Automation.

I have few logs recorded in server side, so when a page refresh happens, those logs are actually getting deleted, which should not happen.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML for this please?

Comment: @Dillanm : Does not have permission to share, but I have added the image for reference.